# If with and without curly braces

Tags: c++, c

I read a question about `if` statement

Which code is faster/same?

> if(a==1) return 0;
>
> if(a==1) { return 0; }

Is there really any difference for speed or for compiler in this case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I bet the compiler finds this question offensive. It's better than that!

Comment: Actually I believe that just by asking this question you spent more time waiting for an answer than all your combined compiler-calls would take to parse that extra pair `{}`.

Comment: The brackets don't matter much; the real difference is due to the parentheses.  `return 0;` is *much* faster than `return(0);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Concerning run-time speed, **they are exactly the same thing**.

The C++11 Standard defines the first form to be an implicit variation of the second form. Per Paragraph 6.4/1, in fact:

> [...] The substatement in a *selection-statement*
>   (each substatement, in the `else` form of the `if` statement) implicitly defines a block scope (3.3). If the substatement in a selection-statement is a single statement and not a *compound-statement*, it is as if
>   it was rewritten to be a *compound-statement* containing the original substatement. [*Example*:
>
> ```
> if (x)
>     int i;
> ```
>
> can be equivalently rewritten as
>
> ```
> if (x) {
>     int i;
> }
> ```
>
> Thus after the if statement, i is no longer in scope. —*end example* ]

The additional compilation time required to parse the extra braces is so small that it can be safely disregarded. **Choose the form which makes the code easier to read or to maintain in your case**.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference in performance except the tiny, tiny, tiny amount of extra time required to parse the braces at compile-time.

Comment: .. and the time needed to put the curly brackets there

Answer (score 3):

Runtime speed is exactly the same. Compilation speed could have differences somewhere around the order of nanoseconds. For all practical reasons and purposes, however, the two statements are identical.

Answer (score 2):

There is *ABSOLUTELY NO* difference in the speed of both statements.

**Premature optimization** is a bad thing. Don't spend a lot of time worrying about such things.